# Logstash "add_field" saves "%{...}" as value when key value pair missing in JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat, logstash-file

```
add_field => {"ExampleFieldName" => "%{[example][jsonNested1][jsonNested2]}"}
```

My Logstash receives a JSON from Filebeat, which contains object `example`, which itself contains object `jsonNested1`, which contains a key value pair (with the key being `jsonNested2`).

If `jsonNested1` exists and `jsonNested2` exists and contains a value, then this value will be saved correctly in `ExampleFieldName` in Elasticsearch.

```
{
    "example": {
        "jsonNested1": {
            "jsonNested2": "exampleValue"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case `ExampleFieldName` would contain `exampleValue`.

```
{
    "example": {
        "jsonNested1": {

        }
    }
}
```

In this case I would like `ExampleFieldName` to contain an empty string or no value at all (or to be not created in the first place).

But it happens that `ExampleFiledName` contains the string `%{[example][jsonNested1][jsonNested2]}`.

I already found a solution for this by checking first if the the nested key value pair exists before performing the `add_field`.

```
if [example][jsonNested1][jsonNested2] {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"ExampleFieldName" => "%{[example][jsonNested1][jsonNested2]}"}
    }
}
```

This solution works, but I can't believe this is the best way to do it. I find it very strange that Logstash even saves `%{[example][jsonNested1][jsonNested2]}` as a string here, when the key value pair doesn't exist. I would expect it to recognize this and to simply not save any value in this case.

The if statement is an acceptable solution if have to check for one field. But currently I'm working on a Logstash config with around 50 fields. Should I create 50 if statements there?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix this using a prune filter, where the default value of [blacklist_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html#plugins-filters-prune-blacklist_names) is to remove unresolved field references.